# Can [maintenance] be kept in good working order?*

Tags: discussion, tags

<sup>*Credit to Eliah Kagan for [the title](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52271295#52271295)</sup>

We have a tag [maintenance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) which currently has 38 questions in it.

The questions relate to a miscellany of topics, since "maintenance" is a very broad category of activity that could apply to many tasks having little in common with each other.

I feel that there is no benefit in having a tag for *maintenance* since it can be applied too broadly to usefully define the subject of questions, and it is unlikely that anyone would take a particular interest in or have a particular expertise in "maintenance" *in general* as opposed to in relation to some specific task or part of the OS. Tasks intended as maintenance can be described more precisely by tags relating to the action itself, such as [package-management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/package-management), its context, such as a particular piece of software, and/or perhaps its goal, such as [performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/performance).

Should this tag be removed from the questions that have it?